# iOS AutoLayout with a long form

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am trying to build a form with about 10 different text fields, switches and labels for iPad and iPhone. In doing so, I want to use AutoLayout with UIScrollView so that it could work well in both iPhone/iPad and portrait/landscape. What I found out is that it would take an hour or two to set up all the autolayout correctly for all devices.

I have also tried to use UITableView and I only need to setup 1 or 2 cell for all the AutoLayout to work properly. The tradeoff is that managing a table view is quite harder than a scroll view

I am not sure if anybody has a better way to set up these kinds of form and lessons they have learnt in doing so

Comment: iOS 9 is introducing a new class called `UIStackView` that makes this kind of layout much easier.

Comment: That is really good to know, although XLForm seems to be a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Try [XLForm](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm) is it a lot better when dealing with forms and has various cell types even you can add your custom cell if you have specific row that is not supported